# the correct way to use Javascript += operator

Tags: javascript

i have this html code

```
<button id="pox" class="here click" value="10"> Posted </button>
<button id="pox1" class="here2 click" value="10"> Posted-Date</button>
```

And this sample JS code

```
var one = document.getElementById("pox").value-=5; 
var one = document.getElementById("pox1").value+=5;
```

the problem is the -=5 returns a 5 value which is what i wanted. but +=5 return 105, how do i make it return 15.

my purpose of adding -=5 or += 5 is to add or subtract 5 each time the button is clicked

Comment: Why are you using different id `pos` instead of `pox` in your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the `value` of the button, then you cannot use a simple `+=` because the value is a string, and so `+=` will concatenate it. If you use simple variables this becomes easier to see:

```
// normal numbers
var aNumber = 1;
aNumber += 5;  // aNumber = 6

// the left hand side is a string, so the right hand side is also converted to a string
var aString = "1";
aString += 5;  // aString = "15";
```

Instead in this case it is better to do 2 operations - parse the value and assign it to a variable and then assign it back.

So either:

```
document.getElementById("pox").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("pox").value, 10) - 5;
document.getElementById("pox1").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("pox1").value, 10) + 5;
```

or a bit more readable and you can store and do something with the value:

```
var one = parseInt(document.getElementById("pox").value, 10);
one -= 5;
document.getElementById("pox").value = one;

var two = parseInt(document.getElementById("pox1").value, 10);
two += 5;
document.getElementById("pox1").value = two;
```